# user-Defined SQL Function gives error "Invalid column name 'Employee_Name'."

Tags: sql

I am working one something and I can't get it to work. I am trying to Create a user defined function named Employee_Name. Pass an Employee Id as a parameter.Return the First Name, Last Name, and Phone Number of the employee whose ID matches the id passed to the user defined function.Create a query that uses the function and returns information for the employee with an id of 5. But In order to finish the function employee name I can not get it to work. I keep getting this error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Employee_Name, Line 10
Invalid column name 'Employee_Name'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'Employee_name'.
```

The code looks like this:

```
   CREATE FUNCTION Employee_Name 
(
    @EmployeeID int 
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT * FROM Employees
    WHERE Employee_Name = @EmployeeId
)
GO

SELECT * FROM Employee_name (1)
```

Now to get the Return on First name,lastname and phone wouldnt I so a select on the employees id where it goes like this

```
Select 
FirstName,
LastName,
PhoneNumber
From EmployeeId
```

Or something like that.Now to get the employee with and Id of 5 would i use the count or  do something that has an =5; I am not to sure still confused.

Edit: This is what I have again:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION Employee_Name 
(
    @EmployeeID int 
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT FirstName,LastName,HomePhone
    FROM Employees
    WHERE Employee_Name = @EmployeeId
)
GO
```

Comment: Which SQL implementation are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
WHERE Employee_Name = @EmployeeId
```

does not make sense. Surely you mean something like

```
WHERE Employees.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
```

?

And this query:

```
Select 
FirstName,
LastName,
PhoneNumber
From EmployeeId
```

should surely be this:

```
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       PhoneNumber
  FROM Employees
 WHERE EmployeeId = ...
```

?

Comment: Yes I did fix that with the select statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE Employee_Name = @EmployeeId <<<-
```

should that be

```
WHERE Employee_Id = @EmployeeId
```

? (or whatever your Id column is named).

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because function has the same name as the column.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees
WHERE Employees.Employee_Name = @EmployeeId
```

or rather

```
SELECT * FROM Employees
WHERE Employees.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
```